Driving H-Bridge Through Inverters Mysteriously drains capacitor
I am trying to control a pair of motors through a MOSFET H-Bridge, with the direction of movement controlled by a timer (schematic below). Once the timer is triggered, the motors will switch direction, and then return to the original direction once the time elapses.
The timing circuit involves a capacitor, which should completely discharge once the timer is triggered. The capacitor then charges through a 100k resistor, eventually triggering a Schmitt trigger inverter. The capacitor should not discharge at all before the entire timer is triggered again. Currently, however, the capacitor is somehow erroneously discharging once the inverter is triggered (scope plot below), and this only occurs once the timing circuit is connected to the H-Bridge. The only path through which the capacitor could discharge is through a MOSFET transistor, which is only controlled by circuitry external to the H-Bridge, so I have no idea how it could be discharging.
I have tried buffering the input to each inverter through an op-amp and adding flyback diodes (unnecessary for MOSFETs?), neither of which solved the problem.




Does the OpAmp use the same supply as the motor stage? Does sound trigger the discharge event?

I am currently using three 9V batteries, giving a -9V and two 9Vs. One 9V goes to the motors and one goes to the rest of the circuit.

It seems odd that you wouldn't mention the microphone and its amplifier, that's the first place I'd look. Given the absence of supply decoupling capacitors, on a supply shared with motors and bridges with shoot-through, that's where my money would be if I were a betting man.

Can you explain your actual intent (you excluded the purpose of the microphone)? Also, how does your oscillator able to switch the direction of the motors using the bottom most NMOS?

You have a 4 channel scope, so measure the OpAmp supply, the OpAmp output and the charge ramp together. Use a much faster timebase (e.g. 10 µs) and trigger on the falling edge of the ramp. I expect to see a negative going transient on the supply, forwarded by the mic and amplified by the OpAmp.
